# How does casting work in this situation?

Tags: java

So let's say I have two classes.

```
public class example1 {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    public example1(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
} 


public class example2 extends example1 {

    public example2(int a, String b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    public int getA() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Now, if I go ahead and cast example2 to type example 1.

```
example1 a = (example1) new example2(5, "Hi");
```

What will a.getA() return?

As a further question from that, if example2 looked like this..

```
public class example2 extends example1 {

    public example2(int a, String b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
    @Override
    public int getA() {
        return getAModified();
    }
    public int getAModified() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

What would a.getA() return? What happens here, and more importantly why does it happen?

Comment: I have to ask why you don't just run the code and find out and then ask why you got the results you did?

Comment: Because I'm trying to figure out what exactly is happening, the end result means very little.

Comment: I understand that. You're asking what the output is and "Even in the...". I'm just wondering why you didn't test your "theories" and present your findings rather than ask what the output would be. Debugging is very helpful because you can see the object types and so forth; that's all.

Answer (score 0):

> What will a.getA() return?

will execute the getA() method of example2 i.e. 10.

Even in your second case, it will return 10.

> Reason here is method overriding

Its getting decided during runtime, which getA() method is getting called.
Since you are creating an object of Example2, hence in both cases the getA() of Example2 is getting called, its overriding the getA() method of Example1.

You are able to cast the object of Example2 to Example1 as it is parent class but it won't change the fact that the object is actually of Example2.

Comment: Even in the second example where I use a method instead? I had a theory (although probably incorrect) that since I was casting example2 to a type which didn't contain getAModified() it wouldn't know how to deal with it

Comment: @Storm-, you wouldn't be able to directly call `a.getAModified()` after the cast, since the casted type doesn't have the method. But the class `example2` can call it (since it knows the object is of type `example2` and example2 class has the method `getAModified()`).

Answer (score 0):

> What would a.getA() return?

Will give you the result from `example2`, since your *instantiated* using the class `example2`

> What happens here

```
example1 a = (example1) new example2(5, "Hi");
```

.
You are creating an instance of type `example1` witn of implementation `example2`. And casting to `example1`.

*Casting* shows the use of an `object` of one type in place of another type. That's it. It won't magically convert the *instantiated* object to casted.